# diff (GNU diffutils) 3.6 exclude directory

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, diff, gnu

Is it possible to exclude directory from comparison by using `diff`?

there is an option `-x` to exclude that works ok with files:

```
diff -x "*.swp" dir1 dir2
```

but I could not get that `-x` working with paths of directories for eg:

```
diff -x "*/tmp/cache*" dir1 dir2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify only the last element :

```
diff -x "cache*" dir1 dir2
```